# JS function with limited number of console.log() repeats

Tags: javascript

Learning some basic concepts in JavaScript "asynchronicity" from Frontendmasters course [JavaScript: The Hard Parts, v2](https://frontendmasters.com/courses/javascript-hard-parts-v2/)

I am given the [exercise (Challenge 5)](http://csbin.io/async):

> Create a function `limitedRepeat` that console logs `"hi for now"` every second, but only for 5 seconds. Research how to use `clearInterval()` if you are not sure how to do this.

And following placeholder was given for this function:

```
function limitedRepeat() {
//CODE HERE
}
```

I was able to solve it as following (2 versions):

**Version 1**

```js
function limitedRepeat() {
  var totalLogs = 0;
  var logFunc = setInterval(myTimer, 1000)
  function myTimer() { 
    if(totalLogs < 5){
      console.log("hi for now");
      totalLogs++;
    } else {
      clearInterval(logFunc);
    }
  }
}
limitedRepeat(); // should log (every second, for 5 seconds): hi for now
```

**Version 2**

```js
function limitedRepeat(totalLogs) {  
  console.log("hi for now");
  var timery = setTimeout(timerable,1000);
  function timerable() {
    totalLogs++;
    if(totalLogs >= 5){
      clearTimeout(timery);
    } else {
      limitedRepeat(totalLogs);
    }
  }
}
limitedRepeat(0); // should log (every second, for 5 seconds): hi for now
```

Obviously, I have changed the signature of function in **Version 2**, so I am curious if there is solution that leverages `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()` and possibly recursion, that doesn't require signature of function to be changed - in other words for that recursive call set by timeout to somehow memorize how many times was the log printed to console?

Comment: My take: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/3vbf0nsm/

Comment: A recursive function has two different parts. The base case and the recursive case. The base case is used to terminate the task from recurring. If base case is not defined, then the function will recur infinite number of times. Therefore unless you use your fn signature to wrap the actually recursive function or use global vars to store state then, to my understanding, you would never know when to execute your base case. because your state would never change (granted the idea was to setup a pure function)

Comment: Taken at face value, solving this is trivial: all I need to do is take your Version 2, rename `limitedRepeat` to `recursion` and wrap the entire thing in `function limitedRepeat() { ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With recursion;

```js
function limitedRepeat(count = 0) {
  if(count >= 5) return;
  console.log('hi')
  setTimeout(() => limitedRepeat(++count), 1000)
}

limitedRepeat()
```

Just make sure you increment before recalling the function.

Comment: Your answer satisfies constraint to run 5 times, but not to run with timed schedule of 1 second. Requirement is to log once each second, no more than 5 times.

Comment: There, fixed. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach:

```js
var count = 1,
timer = setInterval(limitedRepeat,1000)

function limitedRepeat() {
console.log('Hi for now');

count++;

if(count > 5) clearInterval(timer)
}
```

Comment: Maintaining any states outside of function call (global scope) is not allowed in this exercise - while it makes things easier, idea is to practice self-contained execution utilizing call stack and event-loop.

Answer (score 1):

Using an inner named IIFE with recursion.

EDIT: We don't even need the closure to memoize the times executed if we pass the parameter to the inner function.

```js
        function limitedRepeat() {
          const maxTimes = 5;
          return (function _limitedRepeat(current) {
            console.log("hi for now");
            var timery = setTimeout(timerable, 1000);
        
            function timerable() {
              current++;
              if (current >= maxTimes) {
                return
              }
              _limitedRepeat(current);
            }
          })(0);
        }
        
        limitedRepeat();
```